# Projection Matrix with PhotoCapture on Hololens 1 not available

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have developed a small application to test the PhotoCapture API of Hololens to capture a screenshot with location matrix. The screenshot is correctly taken and adding as texture on a gameobject, but the methods TryGetProjectionMatrix and TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix return always false. Despite hours of research on the Web, I does not find why the location data are not accessible. I have tried on the play mode of unity (computer) and on the Hololens directly, but the result is the same.

I need them because I must extracted the pixels of the real environment behind the virtual elements.

Unity version: 2019.4.27f1
Hololens version: 1
Hololens SDK: 10.0.17763.0
Capabilities activated: InternetClient, WebCam, Microphone, SpatialPerception, GazeInput

You can find below the script associated to the main camera under MixedRealityPlayscape.

I hope that someone can help me.
Best regards,
Maxime

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam;

public class AutomaticColorAdaptation : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate(PhotoCapture captureObject) {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters(WebCamMode.PhotoMode);
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;
         
            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result) {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        Debug.Log(result.success); // Display True
        Debug.Log(photoCaptureFrame.hasLocationData); // Display False

        Matrix4x4 m1 = new Matrix4x4();
        Matrix4x4 m2 = new Matrix4x4();

        Debug.Log(photoCaptureFrame.TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix(out m1)); // Display False
        Debug.Log(photoCaptureFrame.TryGetProjectionMatrix(out m2)); // Display False

        Debug.Log(m1); // Display Identity matrix
        Debug.Log(m2); // Display Identity matrix

        // Copy the raw image data into our target texture
        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

        // Create a gameobject that we can apply our texture to
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        Renderer quadRenderer = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>() as Renderer;
        quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));

        quad.transform.parent = this.transform;
        quad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

        quadRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", targetTexture);

        // Deactivate our camera
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }

    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        // Shutdown our photo capture resource
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like an issue at the Unity layer or below, and there is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/7224) on the GitHub reporting the same behavior, and it has been closed on Jul 13. Could you upgrade your Unity to the [latest version](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) and try again?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying with the version 2019.4.31f1 and 2020.3.21f1 but no progress. The problem persist.

Comment: We try to reproduce this issue with your code but failed, it always returns "True" for us. We are using Unity 2019.4.22 and MRTK 2.7.2. And the OS Version of our HoloLens1 device is 10.0.17763.134, could you please check for updates in Settings to see If there is a system update available for your HoloLens?

Comment: I will try to update the devices Monday, but the methods doesn't work on unity play mode ? This is a link to my project: https://we.tl/ t-aYnrc6Mk9i (without the space between / and t). Perhaps you have another configuration than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new project with Unity 2019.4.27f1 and MRTK 2.7.2. This time, I have not cloned the MRTK profile to disable the CPU performer bar. It's working on my Hololens 1. My problem is solved. Thanks to Hernando for his answers.